# How can I get a SVG path shape to scale on zoom in D3?

Tags: svg, d3.js

Given my [example here](http://bl.ocks.org/activeshadow/86f232f4b1ca485dfd91/05365fba70c962cce65d1f6ec5d7c098e9aac54f), how can I get the location markers on the map to scale when I zoom in/out on the map? Based on what I've read, I *think* I need to use a `tween` function via `attrTween` but I don't really know what that means.

Comment: You could scale the markers separately. No need for a custom tween.

Comment: Awesome Lars, I'm all about not having to use a custom tween. But I still don't know how to scale a path object based on the current zoom level...

Comment: Well the zoom level you can get through `zoom.scale()`. Then all you need to do is assign a `transform` attribute with the scale computed according to that to the `path`s of your markers. On a separate note, SVG also provides [markers as separate entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/marker), which may or may not make what you're trying to achieve easier.

Comment: OK, thanks Lars. I'll try that out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Lars I'm still not seeing where/how to add the transform to my example... :(

Comment: Nevermind... got it to work. Thanks!!! If you want to post as an actual answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current zoom level through `zoom.scale()`. This you can then use to compute the scale factor for the marker `path`s such that they remain the same size. All you then need to do is apply this scale in a `transform` attribute for those `path`s.